# Traefik - How to configure a service in docker-compose using a dynamic yaml file

Tags: traefik

For the following docker compose file for traefik:

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.10
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - C:\\Users\\juann\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Development\\TraefikTests:/etc/traefik
      - C:\\Users\\juann\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Development\\TraefikTests\\logs:/traefik/logs
      - C:\\Users\\juann\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Development\\TraefikTests\\config:/traefik/config
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true

  whoami:
    image: traefik/whoami
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.docker.localhost`)"
```

I want to configure the information in the second label of container **whoami** in a traefik dynamic configuration file. For that, I created *whoami.yml" like this:

```
http:
  routers:
    whoami:
      entryPoints:
        - "mydashboard"
      service: "whoami"
      rule: 'Host(`{{ "whoami.docker.localhost" }}`)'
```

The problem is traefik reports error:

> {"entryPointName":"mydashboard","level":"error","msg":"the service "whoami@file" does not exist","routerName":"whoami@file","time":"2024-02-03T14:18:20Z"}

inside the log file when I execute *docker compose up*.

Obviously, the service name **whoami** is not correct.
What would be the correct way to do this with a traefik dynamic configuration file (not inside the docker-compose.yml)?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following *whoami.yml* file works:

```
http:
  services:
    whoami:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - address: "http://whoami"
  routers:
    whoami:
      entryPoints:
        - "web"
      service: "whoami"
      rule: 'Host(`{{ "whoami.docker.localhost" }}`)'
```

Everything is clearer after a short "siesta" and some reading about how providers actually work in Traefik. What I was trying to do here is to reference a service found by the docker provider inside the file provider. What I needed to do is to tell the file provider where to find this service (where it is running).